# Python parsing json issue

Tags: python, json

I'm having troubles parsing a complicated json. That is it:

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "bar": "76561198034360615",
                "foo": "49329432943232423"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

My code:

```
url = urllib.urlopen("foobar").read()
js = json.load(url)
data = js['response']
print data['players']
```

The problem is that this would print the dict. What I want is to reach the key's values, like `foo` and `bar`. What I tried so far is doing `data['players']['foo']` and it gives me an error that list indices should be integers, I tried of course, it didn't work. So my question is how do I reach these values? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data['response']['players']` is an array (as defined by the brackets (`[, ]`), so you need to access items using a specific index (0 in this case):

```
data['players'][0]['foo']
```

Or iterate over all players:

```
for player in data['response']['players']:
    print player['foo']
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot how to select them exactly. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that players is a list of items (`[ ]` in json). So you need to select the first and only item in this case using `[0]`.

```
print data['players'][0]['foo']
```

But, keep in mind that you may have more than one player, in which case you either need to specify the player, or loop through the players using a for loop

```
for player in data['players']:
    print player['foo']
```

Comment: Haha, yea I saw he was like 60s before me. :)